# Configuring PAM with Augeas

Tags: ubuntu, puppet, pam, augeas

I am attempting to use Augeas to configure the files in my /etc/pam.d directory in a default Ubuntu 14.04 install. My goal is to find all nodes that have an argument of either 'nullok' or 'nullok_secure' and remove those arguments from the configuration. This will eventually be enforced by Puppet, but I am currently working out the configuration using augtool on a local machine.

From everything I have read, the following expressions SHOULD yield me the nodes with 'nullok and 'nullok_secure':

```
augtool print /files/etc/pam.d/*/*/argument[../argument = 'nullok']
augtool print /files/etc/pam.d/*/*/argument[../argument = 'nullok_secure']
```

Or, alternately:

```
augtool print /files/etc/pam.d/*/*/argument[. = 'nullok']
augtool print /files/etc/pam.d/*/*/argument[. = 'nullok_secure']
```

Unfortunately, these aren't getting me anywhere, and I can't, for the life of me, figure out why. This is the `augtool print` of the one files I know has the argument (with comments removed for briefness):

```
/files/etc/pam.d/common-auth
/files/etc/pam.d/common-auth/1
/files/etc/pam.d/common-auth/1/type = "auth"
/files/etc/pam.d/common-auth/1/control = "[success=2 default=ignore]"
/files/etc/pam.d/common-auth/1/module = "pam_unix.so"
/files/etc/pam.d/common-auth/1/argument = "nullok_secure"
/files/etc/pam.d/common-auth/2
/files/etc/pam.d/common-auth/2/type = "auth"
/files/etc/pam.d/common-auth/2/control = "[success=1 default=ignore]"
/files/etc/pam.d/common-auth/2/module = "pam_lsass.so"
/files/etc/pam.d/common-auth/2/argument = "try_first_pass"
/files/etc/pam.d/common-auth/3
/files/etc/pam.d/common-auth/3/type = "auth"
/files/etc/pam.d/common-auth/3/control = "requisite"
/files/etc/pam.d/common-auth/3/module = "pam_deny.so"
/files/etc/pam.d/common-auth/4
/files/etc/pam.d/common-auth/4/type = "auth"
/files/etc/pam.d/common-auth/4/control = "required"
/files/etc/pam.d/common-auth/4/module = "pam_permit.so"
/files/etc/pam.d/common-auth/5
/files/etc/pam.d/common-auth/5/type = "auth"
/files/etc/pam.d/common-auth/5/control = "optional"
/files/etc/pam.d/common-auth/5/module = "pam_cap.so"
```

What am I missing here? Shouldn't these commands give me the nodes I am looking for?

Answer (score 1):

First, the two expressions you list are not stricly equivalent.

```
/files/etc/pam.d/*/*/argument[../argument = 'nullok']
```

selects `argument` nodes 2 levels under `/files/etc/pam.d` that have an `argument` sibling node (or themselves) with a value set to `nullok`, whereas

```
/files/etc/pam.d/*/*/argument[. = 'nullok']
```

selects `argument` nodes 2 levels under `/files/etc/pam.d` with a value set to `nullok` (but not their siblings, if any).

Now the problem you're having is that the `argument` nodes you're trying to match are actually **3** levels under `/files/etc/pam.d`, not 2, so you'd need another level of `/*`.

The easiest way to avoid counting levels would be match at any level, by using `//` instead:

```
/files/etc/pam.d//argument[.='nullok']
```

That said, I don't know what you plan on doing with it, but you might want to know that there is an [Augeas-based Puppet provider to manage PAM entries](http://augeasproviders.com/documentation/examples.html#pam-provider), which might be much easier than reimplementing your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

After working through some things in the Augeas IRC room, it appears that my issue was simply a syntax error. When using "augtool print" directly (without dropping into the augtool> prompt), paths must be quoted. Meaning,

```
augtool print /files/etc/pam.d/*/*/argument[. = 'nullok_secure']
```

Will not work, but:

```
augtool print '/files/etc/pam.d/*/*/argument[. = "nullok_secure"]'
```

Yields the correct results. Also, if you drop into the augtool prompt, the command works correctly, even without quotes:

```
$ augtool
augtool> print /files/etc/pam.d/*/*/argument[. = 'nullok_secure']
```